# Magento VAT tax calculation with countries with different tax percentage is calculated incorrectly

Tags: magento2, vat, taxes

I have been using Magento for about 7 years and am pretty familiar with the platform.

I recently added a new website to my installation that requires general VAT calculations.

Here is the issue:

- Country A: 20% VAT tax (Country for Default Tax Destination Calculation (Magento setting)
- Country B: 25% VAT tax
- Product price is €9.95 (including VAT tax). The product price shows up correctly on the product page.
- Product price shows correctly if Country A is selected during checkout

Price Including VAT: €9.95,
Price Excluding VAT: €9.29,
VAT: €1.66

- When country B is selected during checkout, the price, including taxes, changes!:

Price including VAT: €10.36,
Price excluding VAT €8.29,
VAT: €2.07

ISSUE: The price, including VAT, should not change when selecting Country B during checkout!!!

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks for any help!